# Center fixed-width CSS3 Multi-columns in container

Tags: css

I'm using CSS3 Multicolumns with column-width set at 200px, leaving column-count free to adapt to different screen sizes.

Here is the code I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/kBPUX/

On my 1280px wide laptop, the columns are centered as the window expands from one to two all the way up to four columns.  It works great but then suddenly at four columns when the window is maximized, the columns all suddenly left justify leaving a big ugly gutter on the right.

Any idea what that's about and how to make columns centered at any resolution?

EDIT: After playing with it some more, I believe what is happening is that the browser doesn't want to make any more columns.  Column-fill is left unspecified so it defaults to auto and tries to match the column heights as closely as possible.  Adding more columns would result in columns with differing heights.  It is at this point that I want to ensure the columns are centered in the parent container, and not left justified.

Notes: This works for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE9 which is all that I'm supporting.  I absolutely will not touch JQuery layout products; it has to be pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `column-count`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Svyy2/4/

Also look at the `div`'s `width`. If you set them to the same `width` as `columns` you will get problems because `width+padding+border` > `column width`. Set it to 90%, for example.

Comment: Can't use column-count because the layout must be responsive to different screen resolutions; that is both desktop and mobile need to be supported by one style.  I could use media queries, but in my opinion that's a terrible solution.

Comment: column-count is responsive. If `available width` < (`column-count` * `column-width`) then fewer columns are displayed. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I don't know of any *working* solutions to my problem, but I believe that the proper solution is the column-space-distribution property of the multicolumn spec, but it isn't implemented by any browser yet.